# "Can't find any matching row in the user table" when attempting "SET PASSWORD"

Tags: mysql

When I do `SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user` I see that I have a user named `myuser` on `%`. I tried setting that users password thusly:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'myuser'@'%' = 'mypassword';
```

Doing so, however, resulted in this error:

```
Error Code: 1133. Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly wildcards in hostnames in this context.  You're explicitly trying to set a password for `'myuser'@'%'`, not any user named `myuser`.

You will need to get a list of users and their hostnames and set the password for each of them if they all should indeed have the same password.

Comment: "_You will need to get a list of users and their hostnames and set the password for each of them_". I did that, as evidenced by my `SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user` comment in my original post...